# Form that Generates a Risk Score

Tags: javascript, html

I'm creating a lengthy form. There's 5 different sections for you to mark off if you qualify (checkmarks).  Probably 50 questions total.  Each section has a different weight/points (section 1 is 1 point each, section 2 is 3 points each etc).  How can I display the total score and does my script calculation look ok? Sorry I'm fairly new at this.  Didn't include the entire form because it's very long.

```
<script language="JavaScript1.1" type="text/javascript">
/* <![CDATA[ */

var calctxt = '';
var xmltxt = '';
var htmtxt = '';

function DVTScoreWells_fx() {
with(document.DVTScoreWells_form){

Score = 0.0;
doCalc = true;

if (1PQ1.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ2.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ3.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ4.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ5.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ6.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ7.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ8.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ9.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ10.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ11.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ12.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ13.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ14.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (1PQ15.checked){
Score = Score + 1;
}
if (2PQ1.checked){
Score = Score + 2;
}
if (2PQ2.checked){
Score = Score + 2;
}
if (2PQ3.checked){
Score = Score + 2;
}

cctotal.value = Score;

if (doCalc){

rrclr();
}
}
}
</script>

<form name="DVTScoreWells_form" id="DVTScoreWells_form" action="#" onsubmit="return false;" onreset="rrclr();">
<br><br>
<p>Are you at risk for DVT?  Fill out this Risk Assessment and take a look.</p><br><br>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</td>
</tr>
</tbody>
</table>
<table bgcolor="#FFFFFF" cellpadding="200" cellspacing="200" class="bodyContainer">
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="leftSidebar" sectionid="leftSidebar" valign="top">
<div>
<div>
<div class="title" style="text-align:left">
<div class="title" contentid="title" style="text-align: left;">
<div>
<div>
<span style="text-decoration: none;"><span style="font-family: Comic Sans MS; font-size: 18pt;">Each Risk Factor 

Represents 1 Point</span></span>
</div>
<div>
&nbsp;
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
</div>
<div>
<table class="infusion-field-container" style="width:270;">
<tbody>
<tr>

<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ1" name="1PQ1" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx();" 

/>
<label for="1PQ1">Age 41 - 59</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ2" name="1PQ2" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx();" 

/>
<label for="1PQ2">Minor surgery planned</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ3" name="1PQ3" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
<label for="1PQ3">History of prior major surgery</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ4" name="1PQ4" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
<label for="1PQ4">Varicose veins</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ5" name="1PQ5" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
<label for="1PQ5">History of inflammatory bowel disease</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ6" name="1PQ6" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
<label for="1PQ6">Swollen legs (current)</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ7" name="1PQ7" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
<label for="1PQ7">Obesity (BMI >30)</label>
</td>
</tr><tr>
</td>
</tr><tr>
<td class="infusion-field-input-container" style="width:270px;">
<input class="infusion-field-input-container" id="1PQ8" name="1PQ8" type="checkbox" onclick="DVTScoreWells_fx

();"/>
```

Comment: LOL true.  Just trying to get everything working before I make it look professional

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Honestly the way your current code approaches this is prone to errors via typos or omission, as well as will be a pain to maintain.

My main suggestion is to leverage a div with the id of Score that contains the running total, and have each checkbox call a function with their value as an argument that adjusts the innerHTML of score, eg:
HTML:
`Your Risk is <span id='risklevel'>Low</span> (<span id='score'>0</span>)`
`<input type='checkbox' onchange='updateScore(this,3);' />`

JS:

```
function updateScore(ele,val){
    var score = document.getElementById('score');
    var riskLevel = document.getElementById('risklevel');

    var curScore = parseFloat(score.innerHTML);
    curScore += (ele.checked ? val : -val);
    score.innerHTML = curScore;

    if(curScore <= 1){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Low";
    }else if(curScore <= 2){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Moderate";
    }else if(curScore <= 4){
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "High";
    }else{
        riskLevel.innerHTML = "Very High";
    }
}
```

**OR**
If you wanna stick with a calc-all-at-once approach...

Tag the checkboxes with their section in some natively dom-searchable way (I suggest classes prefixed with data- (eg: *data-riskFactorSet* )), give each one a data-* attribute (such as *data-riskvalue*) and have your js iterate over all checkboxen, combining the int/float value of the data-* attribute.

NOTE: since it's a less popular construct...
`(ele.checked ? val : -val)` uses a Ternary operator. Think of it like an in-line *if-then-else* statement, with the stipulation that the return types of the true and false parts must be the same. It works like this:

`test ? ifTrue : ifFalse`

Comment: Thank you very much.  I'm new at coding and way over my head :(  It's working good on my small test but sometimes if I click the checkbox a few times real fast the score will jump higher or lower then it should be.  Right now I'm only testing it with one box.  Is there any tweaks needed to the java function?  Thanks again.

Comment: Which, yours or mine?

Comment: I'm using your JS code.  Everything is functioning great and really appreciate your help.  Just notice if I click the same box twice really fast the calculation doesn't add up correctly.  http://manamed.net/risk.html

Comment: Okay first off, you wanna nix the extra checkbox (the one in my HTML) and fix the </div> I used (I typo'd originally) if you haven't already.
As for the double click being an issue, uh.... what browser are you using, I'm not having this issue.

Comment: Thanks, looks a lot better now.  The math glitches with IE 10 when you double click a checkbox but I just tried it with Google Chrome and it's working perfectly.  Must be an IE glitch.

Comment: Question.  How can I display "Your at low risk" if score is less 0-1, "Your at moderate risk" if score is 2, "Your at High Risk if score is 3-4" and your at the Highest Risk if score is 5+    Thanks again for everything!

Comment: To fix the IE thing, use onchange instead of onclick. Reason: `The glitch is caused by how IE throws onclick on every click (not sure if Chrome/FF are just faster at it or if they're treating each onclick as atomic). Using onchange is not only more semantically correct, but also avoids this issue.`

Comment: I'll throw another edit to the solution to do that as well. You're basically just testing what the div's value is when you update it. Gimme a moment.

Comment: @JeffS Editing done (also cleaned up the edit notes). If you're having an issue with Firefox persisting the values, the easiest way is to add `autocomplete="off"` to all the checkboxen. Other options include having a hidden input that stores the score and re-up the display from that on change and on load, and using the other method (the OR part in my answer).

Comment: Thank you so much abluejelly everything is working great.  I greatly appreciate it!

Comment: @JeffS no prob. If you could, accept this answer as the answer.